# How to Control Total Size of Data Produced in Multiple Batches using Spark Kafka Producer in Java

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-producer-api

I have a Spark Kafka Producer(written in Java) which runs in batch on a daily basis. I want to control the size of the data being produced per day.

Let's say I want to produce 100 GB size data total (all batches combined) in a day in multiple batches, and then I want to stop the process. How can I calculate and save the size (in bytes) of data being produced in each batch, so that I can stop the process once the total has hit the 100 GB mark?

Below are the APIs i am using in producer:

```java
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RecordMetadata;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Callback;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
```

The Producer looks like:

```java
public void produceData(String key, String val) {
    
    if (null == kafkaProducer) {
        
        kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(<Kafka Parameters>);
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                kafkaProducer.close();
            }
        });
        
    }
    
    if (key != null) {
        
        kafkaProducer.send(new ProducerRecord(topic, key, val), new ProducerCallback(key, val) {
            public void flush() {
                if (null != kafkaProducer) {
                    kafkaProducer.flush();
                }
            }
        });
        
    }
}
```